# Telerik RadgridView horizontal scrollbar is very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

We are using Telerik RadGridView and we are doing grouping of data in the grid , we have to show group and column footer both , Grid contains 30 columns which is using some styles , converter and some of the columns are having some controls also, We have enabled row and column virtualizing both. So because of that horizontal scrollbar in grid is very slow. Can we get any help on this?
below is the radgridview configuration I am using.

```
 <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="RadGridView"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}"
                                 FrozenColumnCount="2"
                                 EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                 ShowGroupFooters="True"
                                 ShowColumnFooters="True"
                                 EnableLostFocusSelectedState="False"
                                 EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                                 NewRowPosition="None"
                                 CanUserSortColumns="False"
                                 CanUserSortGroups="False"
                                 AutoExpandGroups="True"
                                  >
```

Comment: You tried to run the application without a debugger attached? depending on how heavy you utilize templating etc. the debugger might take up a hell lot of time

Comment: yes I tried without debugger but still its taking lot of time.

Comment: Perhaps you can contact [Telerik Support](https://www.telerik.com/support)? They are always very helpful.

Comment: I have raised the same to telerik waiting from them also to reply.